# Split mechanical keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ergonomics

Is there any sensible solution to the "Shoulders are wider than the keyboard" wrist-pain issue? I am currently spending 6-8 a day in terminal/vim, and I would be willing to invest in a solution to lighten this burden on my wrist. I found an image that illustrates my problem perfectly:
[image]

I currently own a [Das Keyboard (Ultimate)](http://www.getdigital.de/images/actionshots/t4/dasKeyboardUltimateEU.jpg), but I work on a [low-profile Apple Aluminium](http://chadwright.files.wordpress.com/2007/08/apple-keyboard-1.jpg) daily. While I thoroughly enjoy the feel of the Apple, the keyboard is quite a bit narrower than my shoulders, and I want to prevent this injury before it develops into something serious.

I also have a [Microsoft Ergonomics 4000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/_base_v1/products/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/mk_nek4000v2_large.jpg), but the feeling of a normal keyboard after years on a mechanical one makes me cringe. How can I alleviate the wrist strain? How do you guys do it?

Comment: purchase recommendations are off topic for SU and this will probably be closed.. I would suggest (as the *other* keyboard nut on SU , that you look at kinesis, maltron and the ergodox keyboards however.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek may I ask your opinion on the '[Truly Ergonomic Keyboard](http://www.trulyergonomic.com/)'? I like the look of it *mostly* because it's the only ergonomic keyboard I've found that has the number 6 on the correct side...

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of ergonomic keyboards - I go with standard mechanicals myself. One of anandtech's reviewers seems to like it though.

Comment: Cheapest solution: Use 2 keyboards side by side :P

Comment: Follow /r/MechanicalKeyboards on reddit to keep up to date. There's Matias Ergo Pro, some nice options that aren't produced yet are keyboard.io and ultimatehackingkeyboard.

Answer (score 3):

You should try the kinesis freestyle (good review here: http://www.bestergonomickeyboard.net/kinesis-keyboard-ergonomic-review/). The keyboard is split in two and you can move the parts around as much as you like. Therefore you can place them where it feels more natural for your shoulders.

Comment: FreeStyle2 isn't mechanical but I think it has a really neat key action for a membrane keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider the [Ultimate Hacking Keyboard](https://ultimatehackingkeyboard.com/).

[image]

Relevant features:

- Truly split design: You can position and orient the keyboard halves in any way you want resulting in a more comfortable posture.
- Mechanical key switches: Providing a more pleasant typing experience than most keyboards.  Available in six different tactile feedbacks, and keycaps for Windows, Mac, or Linux.
- 60% size: Only includes the alphanumeric block, making it easier to reach the mouse.
- Layered design: Allows you to access the missing keys that are outside of the alphanumeric block via layer switcher keys (three special modifier keys that map navigation and function keys, media keys, and mouse emulation).
- Fully programmable: You can bind shortcuts to any key on any layer. This way, for example, you can trigger Alt+Tab without leaving the home row.
- You can even control the mouse pointer with keys without installing any special drivers.

Unfortunately, it's not yet available in the marketplace.  They have a kickstarter campaign, but for now we can only drool.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just edited my answer to include some relevant points.

Answer (score 2):

I just recently saw this article about the ErgoDox keyboard, which might work for you: http://www.anandtech.com/show/7245/ergodox-review-an-ergonomic-mechanical-keyboard-via-massdrop

Answer (score 1):

The [Comfort Keyboard Original](http://amzn.to/1cNXTpu) has split sections that can be moved farther apart. They are mounted on ball bearings, so you can also twist/tilt them as much as you'd like. Also has custom lower-force mechanical Cherry switches.

Answer (score 1):

Kinesis advantage keyboard. It's really nice.

Kinesis freestyle is good also, and goes wider.

Both use cherry keys I believe. The advantage definitely does.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ergonomic keyboards out there, and some are weirder than the other (for the sake of ergonomics I guess). There are also Mechanical Ergonomic Keyboard if you really want one, but they all come with a fairly hefty price tag simply because they have "ergonomic" tag on them.

I can't vouch for other people typing problem, but somehow I don't have that issue that you pictured in the question. I am a fairly big bodied person and with wide shoulder (I tend to get 3XXL shirts as a guess of my width), and I have been using MS Keyboard 600 (pretty standard width keyboard to my knowledge) without any arm rest.

Now that I actually pay attention to my hand and wrist placement, I don't bend my wrist straight in front of the keyboard as pictured. Even the fact that my keyboard is straight, I still let my wrist flows naturally straight. It does make some fingers stretch to reach certain button but I never had any wrist / RSI issue as I do keep my wrist straight and let my finger do the extra reaching works).

I simply put my hands closer to the keyboard (somewhat on top of the keyboard) and not resting my wrist on the table. I did rest my wrist on the table in the past, it made my wrist tired easier - so have the wrist off the table is better for me. Maybe if I use a proper wrist cushion it would be better, but I have never tried one and happy without one.